# Google Apps Script を停止する方法

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Apps JavaScriptをはじめたところです。
Doc/Gmailから本人あてに誤つて”Hello World!”発信しまったようで、発信方法も再現できないため、停止ができず、困っていますいます、ご教示ください。１週前から、現在も１時間二回の発信\受信を繰り返して居ます。よろしくお願いします。

nsoga

Answer (score 2):

10666と重複していました。タイミングおかしいことになりましたが10666がクローズ票入ってたのでこちらを正として回答します。

スクリプトファイルは、google driveへ保存されています。
https://drive.google.com/
スクリプトファイルを、削除しましょう。
内容が気になるようであれば、ダブルクリックして、suggested～からGoogle Apps Scriptを選べばスクリプト編集のページへ移動できます
[image: google drive]

もし不安でしたらgoogleのマイアカウントの「権限」を確認しましょう
https://myaccount.google.com/
Connected apps and services > Account permissions です。
選択すると右側に「revoke」ボタンがありますので。そこから権限を削除できます。
なおgoogle driveからスクリプトファイルを削除すると。
権限一覧からも自動的に削除されます。
[image: google myaccount permissions]